# SSRS-2008 Editing Tablix Control

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have to create new Report from existing report in SQL Server Reporting service, I am newbie to SQL Server Reporting, this is my first attempt

Here Problem is that all data are in tablix control called table1, how i can edit this tablix control to add new fields in it and remove some existing control from it

Current report is working fine

[image: How to Remove this Table Boundries]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys, Problem was with my VS2008, don't know some configuration errors was there, but it worked great on other PC, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

With the problematic table selected, try navigating the menu to **Format > Order > Send To Back**.  Hopefully this will reveal the elements that are hidden behind.

Comment: What is the purpose of table1?

Comment: I think it's working as a place holder, but don't know exactly

Comment: Can you find out how it is working?  Without knowing what it is for, it's hard to help any further.

Comment: it's tablix, than how to edit tablix ? i want to add new fields in existing tablix

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you increase the body height, drag the table down, select the components, drag them inside the table and them drag the table up again?